# How to use Laravel Eloquent with complex queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to setup Eloquent for a new API that we're working on. I am using relations in a model.

Some relations are complex and aren't really suitable for a quick chained Query Builder statement. For example, I am trying to return metrics and some of those metrics are complex. Such as counting the total clicks generated by a user (it's not just a simple `COUNT(*)`). Here is the code that I have now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Affiliate extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'user';

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Eloquent\Profile', 'id');
    }

    public static function clicks()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT 
                   user_id,
                   COUNT(*) / SUM(dummy_metric) AS total_clicks
                FROM clicks
                WHERE something = 'true' 
                     AND another_thing > 100 # dummy filter for example only
                GROUP BY user_id";

        $rows = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));

        // (PSUEDO CODE) THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO IDEALY
        return $this->belongsTo($rows, user_id);

    }
```

Possible? I'd like to be able to write our own queries without relying on Query Builder all of the time, but I still want to be able to join the relation to Eloquent.

Comment: if I understood correctly , you want to convert your raw SQL to Eloquent querry ?

Comment: @jaysingkar Yes. We have giant queries and I'd like to integrate them into Eloquent somehow.

Comment: something like this ? `Click::select(DB:raw("user_id, COUNT(*) / SUM(dummy_metric) AS total_clicks"))->where(/*condition*/)->groupBy("user_id")->get();` . Assuming you have `Clicks` model defined

Comment: where method accepts an array of conditions, so you can add  more conditions in same where method

Comment: @jaysingkar I see. I guess I am not familiar with how to decide `Clicks`. Would I create a new model for Clicks containing the `belongsTo` and include `use App\Models\Eloquent\Click;` ?

Comment: it depends on your database structure. since you have used select from Clicks I assumed you have `Clicks` table in your DB. If it is so, you would need to define the model for it.

Comment: Assuming, you have 2 tables for `User` and `Entity`, where entity is the one user is going to click(Advertisement banner for example). Then you can create a pivot table with fields (user_id,banner_id), where each entry would denote a click by user on that banner.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `Clicks` model defined, find below the eloquent version of your query.

```
Click::select(DB:raw("user_id, COUNT(*) / SUM(dummy_metric) AS total_clicks"))
        ->where(/*condition*/)->groupBy("user_id")->get();
```

Note:
1) Where method accepts an array of conditions, so you can add more than one condition in same method. [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

**Update**

I think thius should be your `clicks()` method:

```
public function clicks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Eloquent\Click',/*relevant ids*/);
}
```

And, now where you want a count of clicks(in controller for example), you can use following query:

```
$user = User::find("user_id")->with('clicks')->get();
$clicks = $user->clicks()->count();
```

To make it more efficient, refer to this article on [Tweaking Eloquent relations](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/)

**Update 2:**

You can use [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) function to retrieve total count
Add following 2 methods in `User` model.(change `clicksCount` string to anything you need )

```
public function clicksCount(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Eloquent\Click')
                ->select(DB:raw("user_id, COUNT(*) count"))
                ->groupBy("user_id");
}

public function getClicksCountAttribute(){
    return $this->clicksCount->count();
}
```

Now, you can use `$user->clicksCount;` to get the count directly.

If you are using Laravel 5.4, you can use `withCount()` method to easily retrieve the count. [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: So something like this https://pastebin.com/Dx96yPsK and this https://pastebin.com/P6mjENKx ?

Comment: @AlexMarkov check the update, your `User` model would probably throw an error for `clicks` method since it is not returning a relation.. Let me know if this update solves your query

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me due to the library that I am using. Is it possible to create a relation with that query right in my Click model?

Comment: @AlexMarkov sorry that it didn't work. Check the new update